# Missing permissions error when using mute command discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have two servers with my bot on it with two groups of friends. On one server, the bot and I both have admin perms, and I can mute someone who doesn't have those perms. On the other server, I'm the owner and the bot has admin, but I can't mute anyone. I get the error 'Missing Permissions'.

Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const ms = require('ms')

module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',

    execute(message, args) {
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send("Please Specify a time and who to mute. For example, '!mute @antobot10 1d' And then send the command. Once the command is sent, type the reason like a normal message when I ask for it!")
        const client = message.client
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use that command!")
        else {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, { time: 600000, max: 1 })
        const timeGiven = args[1]

       
        message.channel.send('The reason?')

        collector.on('collect', m => {
            
        collector.on('end', d => {
            const reason = m
        
            message.channel.send(`${target} has been muted`)
            target.send(`You have been muted on ${message.guild.name} for the following reason: ***${reason}*** for ${timeGiven}`)
            if(message.author.client) return;
            

        })
            
        })

        let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "MUTE");

           
           target.roles.add(mutedRole)
           
               
              

        setTimeout(() => {
            
                    target.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
            target.send('You have been unmuted.')
            
          }, (ms(timeGiven))

           )
        
        
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bot's role is below the role of the user you are attempting to mute, there will be a `missing permissions` error. In your server settings, drag and drop the bot role as high in the hierarchy it will go. This will solve your problem.

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that the Muted role itself is higher than any of the bot's roles. Anyone with manage roles can give any user roles that are below them.

Comment: Muted should have no permissions, and should be at the very bottom of the list of roles. What I said above causes the problem most frequently

Comment: Yes, but clearly the bot's highest role is lower than the muted role if there is a permission error.

Comment: ^ After reading your points back again, you are saying exactly the same thing as I am

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not exactly sure what I did, but it's working now. I think I just changed it so that the MUTE role had 0 permissions instead of normal permissions but making it so that if you have the role you can't talk in that certain channel.

Thanks for the answers!